# Error al usar FlexBox en Angular

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, frontend

Estoy intentando usar flexbox para colocar en horizontal los cards que estoy creando donde pondré un libro en cada card simulando una tienda de libros.

El problema es que no me está cogiendo bien el flexbox y al hacer display:flex en el container, no cambian de posición los cards nose por lo que puede ser por que los estilos si que me coge el color y la anchura pero el display:flex, no lo hace bien.

```
<div class="book-container"> 
    <div class="book-info">
        <div class="book-image"></div>
        <h1 class="book-info-title">{{book.name | uppercase}}</h1>
        <h3>{{book.description}}</h3>
        <p class="product-info-description">{{book.description}}</p>
        <div class="product-info-price">
            <h1>{{book.price | number | currency}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="book-action">
            <button  [disabled]="!(book.unitAvailable > 1)" class="book-action-btnBuy">Comprar</button>
            <button  class="book-action-btnAdd">+ Carro</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.book-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
.book-info {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px;
    -ms-border-radius:10px 10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px 10px;
}
```

Creo que el problema puede ser que he usado un ngFor para mostrar cada card y por eso me esta dando problemas.

```
<div class="books">
        <ng-container class="card-container" *ngFor="let book of books">
        <div class="book">
         <app-book-card [book]="book"></app-book-card>
        </div>
        </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega el css de esta clase `card-container`